# ActionScript 3 - Possible to access MovieClips which are an instance of another MovieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, instance, movieclip

I drew an image on the stage and converted it to a movieclip whose name is

```
originalMovieClip
```

. The movieclip is now in my library. I dragged the movieclip in my library onto the stage. I did this twice, so now I have two movieclips which are both an instance of

```
originalMovieClip
```

which was the original movieclip which I created.

Through actionscript 3, is there a way for me to target all movieclips which are an instance of

```
originalMovieClip
```

? I want to basically do

```
all Movieclips Which Are An Instance Of originalMovieClip.gotoAndStop(2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such a basic manner, the short answer is - NO.

Short story long - you need to put them into array and loop through it, and stop every movie clip inside.
Other technique (not appropriate) is to loop through all children of stage, and check if the MovieClip is specific type (again you should at least set linkage class to originalMovieClip).

I suggest using the first one :)

Comment: whoops, okay thanks. I just realized that my issue was a bit different than what I initially thought. This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22638987/actionscript-3-targeting-multiple-movieclips-who-have-the-same-instance-name is my real issue.